# How to solve this question of algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

If $y = l + m\sqrt{2}$ such that $l$ and $m$ are non-zero integers, then can $y = \sqrt[3]{6 + 3\sqrt{4}}$?

If yes, find two such integers and if no, explain why no two integers
have this property.

Comment: So, did I understand correctly, you're looking for (non-trivial) integer solutions to
$$
(p + \sqrt{2} q)^3 = x^3 = 5 + 3\sqrt{2}
$$ ?

Comment: Your last edit has mangled the question to the point of it being nonsense. If @MattiP.'s guess was correct, then you should revert the edit.

Comment: @Alex00 it is really bad form to edit your question immediately after you have received an answer, especially since the question has changed completely due to the edit. It doesn't even make sense now; what's $l$?

Comment: hi so sorry for editing the reason for doing so is that i was told  that my teacher has posted this question for another algebra 2 class. She had given it to me yesterday to see how hard it is and i told her it is pretty hard but i was still stuck over it so i asked it here. after your reply I told her about the solution sending her this link and she told me to delete it immediately but i was unable to do so, so i did that.

Comment: @Alex00 well, you've posted the question, the edit history is publicly viewable, and I'm certainly not removing my answer anytime soon. How does editing and vandalising the question help?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose $p+q\sqrt2=\sqrt[3]{5+3\sqrt2}$. Cubing both sides, $p^3+6pq^2+(3p^2q+2q)\sqrt2= 5+3\sqrt2$. Comparing coefficients, this tells you that
$$\begin{cases}p^3+6pq^2=5,\\3p^2q+2q=3.\end{cases}$$
Both equations are diophantine, and has the nice property that the right hand side is a prime. Furthermore, both left hand sides are easily factorisable. When is the product of two integers a prime?

Comment: Diophantine just means the quantities involved are integers. As mentioned in your question, $p,q$ are nonzero integers. Since you've found that the only solutions for $p,q$ are $0.9...$ and $0.7...$, they are obviously not integers, so no integer solutions exist!

Comment: Well, the first equation gives you $p(p^2+6q^2)=5$. Since the second factor is greater than the first, if $p$ is a positive integer, we must have $p=1$ and $p^2+6q^2=5$ (since $5$ is prime and no other factorisations exist). If $p$ is not necessarily positive, then you must discuss the cases $p=-1$ and $p=-5$ too. Do all of that to reach a set of possible values for $(p,q)$, then substitute into the second equation to see whether they satisfy it. If none satisfy, there are no solutions. If some do, they are all of your solutions.